# c# how to capture Ctrl-R from a textbox

Tags: c#, keystroke

I have a from that has a text box and I'm trying to determine if Ctrl-R is pressed within this text box. I can detect the keys separately using:

```
private void CheckKeys(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.R)
    {
        // ...
    }
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How do I determine if they pressed at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible, change your event to `KeyDown`/`KeyUp`, everything will be easier. (Note that this solution is not always applicable)

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.R))
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: I think this will work however i think in my case i will actually want to catch the KeyUP event.  The reason is KeyDown will get sent out a ton if you hold it down.  Thanks Danny.

Comment: I like this method in KeyUp event. simple and easy to understand as well as easy to code. also one can check for other key combination if needed by adding else if....

Answer (score 3):

See Mitch's answer on how to construct the bit flag logic correctly, as long as he undeletes it.  Here's something that will work, if he doesn't decide to.  You basically need to check if both conditions are true at the same time:

```
bool isRKeyPressed = e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.R;
bool isControlKeyPressed = (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control;

if (isRKeyPressed && isControlKeyPressed)
{
    // Both ...
}
else if (isRKeyPressed)
{
    // R key only ...
}
else if (isControlKeyPressed)
{
    // CTRL key only ...
}
else
{
    // None of these...
}
```

Throw away any of these checks that you don't care about.

Also, you might want out check out this alternative approach:
http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/article.php/c4639

They override the `ProcessCmdKey` method on their form (possibly on individual controls?):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx

Comment: +1 for the "check at the same time" logic, and the suggestion to override the `ProcessCmdKey` method. Although, I recommend doing it on the `TextBox` control that you want to capture Ctrl+R from, not on the form as a whole. You only want to catch that if the textbox is focused, so why put it at the form level?

Comment: I tried this but isRKeyPressed returns false always.  isControlKeyPressed is true though.  e.KeyChar is 18 when Ctrl-r is pressed... it is 114 when R is pressed alone.  I was thinking about just checking if e.KeyChar == 18 but i am not sure if this might cause another problem.  Doesn't seem like the best approach to me

Comment: @poco: It wouldn't cause a problem, except that magic numbers ("18") are considered by many people to be bad form.  If you can possibly use a constant from the `Keys` enum, then you should.  As far as I can tell, "18" should map to the Alt key (`Keys.Menu`), so maybe you've got something strange going on with your keyboard.